# WooCommerce: как отключить оплату?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Нужно отключить оплату, чтобы при отправке корзины просто на ящик приходила заявка с данными заказа и покупателя, а менеджер бы просто связывался с заказчиком. Как это можно сделать?

Answer (score 1):

Оставьте только один метод оплаты - оплата при доставке (Cash on Delivery, COD)

Comment: @NikitaSmith это вы так думаете, потому что не знаете, как устроен WooCommerce. Ответ писал по памяти, но сейчас протестировал его - всё ровно так, как просит автор вопроса.

Comment: @NikitaSmith, является ответом.